# Sql, how to get data in difference of 24 hours

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

```
Select p.uhid,p.inpatientno,dateof admission 
from adt.inpatientmaster p 
where p.uhid='apd1' and status <>0
```

Here `uhid` is unique. I want to check that a patient gets admitted  in between 24 hours , here if patient gets admitted again then `uhid` remains same but `inpatientno` always change.

Ex:

```
Registraionno  inpatientno  dateofadmission
Apd1           xy1           18/01/15
Ap1            ab2            19/01/15
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive and state the table names and properties so we can help make a query for you

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Please provide sample data together sample output: that is show us records which would match your desired criteria and records which wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

We can do arithmetic on Oracle dates.  So yesterday is `sysdate - 1`.

You need to query the table twice.  Once to find the patient records, and once to find any previous matches.  Use a self-join to achieve this:

```
select p1.uhid,
       p1.inpatientno as current_inpatientno,
       p1.dateofadmission as current_dateofadmission
       p2.inpatientno as previous_inpatientno,
       p2.dateofadmission as previous_dateofadmission
from adt.inpatientmaster p1 
     join adt.inpatientmaster p2
          on p2.uhid = p1.uhid
where p1.uhid='apd1' 
and p1.status <> 0 
and p2.dateofadmission >= p1.dateofadmission-1
and p2.inpatientno != p1.inpatientno
/
```

You may need to restrict on `p2.status <> 0` as well: not sure what your business rules are.

This query will return one row for each match.  If there are several admissions within the same 24 hours the result set will have one row for each combination.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.uhid,
       p.inpatientno,
       p.dateofadmission
FROM adt.inpatientmaster p
WHERE p.status<>0
  AND p.dateofadmission <= p.dateofadmission +1
  AND p.uhid='APD1'
```

Comment: Um, `p.dateofadmission <= p.dateofadmission +1` is always going to be true.